# How to forward declare clock_gettime()

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gettime

I'm using `clock_gettime()` in `cpp` project.
But it gives `clock_gettime()` not declared in this scope error.
Clearly, someone else has already included `time.h`, hence this error is expected.
But how do I forward declare `clock_gettime()`?
I tried `int clock_gettime(int,struct timespec *)`?

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime, here the declaration is: 
`int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);`

Comment: What does _"hence can't this error is expected."_ mean? And what is a `cpp` project? Do you mean C++? Why not say so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare library functions by including the header that contains the declaration. `time.h` in this case. Writing the declaration yourself is error prone. For example, you declared the first argument as `int` which is not necessarily same as `clockid_t`.

> Clearly, someone else has already included time.h

You should never assume that "someone else" has included the headers that you need. Always include every header yourself that you use.

EDIT:

> Yes. i have already included time.h

If that's the case, then it would appear that your `time.h` does not declare `clock_gettime`. You'll need to double check that your c library supports POSIX.

> hence this error is expected

If you do include the header, then it's **not** expected that `clock_gettime` isn't declared. Unless your c library does not support POSIX.

Comment: @bhushan23 in that case double check that your c library supports POSIX.

Comment: @user2079303 regarding your edit, from the question being tagged [tag:gcc] and [tag:g++], I assumed `glibc` was used (and that was the case I answered) -- of course you can't be sure, just want to add that other C libraries might also support *feature test macros* -- so a C library not supporting POSIX is not the only possibility ;)

Comment: @user2079303 and by the way, a C library declaring `clock_gettime` without the appropriate feature test macro set wouldn't be *strictly* POSIX compliant

Comment: @FelixPalmen what use would support for feature test macros be for using a POSIX function if the library doesn't support POSIX? Maybe I don't quite understand what you're saying.

Comment: @FelixPalmen you're correct. Besides checking that their library supports POSIX, they should check whether their system enables the support by default (such as Linux does) and if not, then define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as appropriate. I would recommend adding the definition to the compilation command rather than the source file.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to declare library functions yourself. `clock_gettime()` **is** declared in `time.h`. What I suppose is "hitting" you here is that `glibc` only makes standard C functions visible by default. For anything else (like e.g. `POSIX` in the case of `clock_gettime()`), you have to define corresponding macros to actually get the declaration. `gcc` does that for some macros automatically, depending on the selected mode (e.g. `-std=gnu99`).

In your case, just adding

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

*before* any include and making sure, `time.h` is included, should do.

(see "Feature Test Macros" part of the manpage)

Comment: That's not true. `glibc` makes a variety of functions visible by default, just not all of them. It's somewhat chaotic.

Comment: @bhushan23 then you didn't describe the problem properly... defining it like this (read carefully) makes the prototype visible.

Comment: @FUZxxl if with "by default", you mean without `__STRICT_ANSI__`, you're correct. But `gcc` sets this as soon as you specify a standard.

Comment: @FelixPalmen when i compile with gcc 4.7 it builds, but with gcc 4.1 it gives above error, Why so?

Comment: @bhushan23 what "above error"? You didn't give an error message *anywhere*

Comment: @FelixPalmen Wow, that must be new. I distinctly remember the glibc being much more lenient a couple of years ago.

Comment: @FUZxxl well, just including its headers without setting `__STRICT_ANSI__` (so e.g. with gcc without a `-std` flag) it *will* declare a lot of non-standard stuff, so you're right. But in a standards-mode, I think it's quite good, although I might have missed some minor errors :)

Comment: @bhushan23 my answer shows the correct (and, btw, documented) way to get the `clock_gettime()` prototype. If this doesn't work for you, please edit your question, adding 1.) your compiler commandline, 2.) the exact error output and 3.) the relevant part of your code. [and I bet you might have avoided getting downvoted doing this in the first place]